# How to integrate expressions with sympy?

Tags: python, expression, sympy, symbolic-integration

I have a problem integrating an expression:

I need to integrate all terms regardless of the variable,

the expression: -x + 2 * (x - 1)

Expected result: -x**2/2 + 2 * ((x - 1)**2) / 2

the code I'm using:

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')

expr = - x + factor(2 * (x - 1))
int_1 = integrate(expr)
print(int_1)
```

generated result: x**2/2 - 2*x

Answer (score 2):

If you check your result you will find it is the same as the original equation, so the answer is right:

```
>>> eq = -x + factor(2 * (x - 1))
>>> integrate(eq).diff()
x - 2
>>> eq.expand()
x - 2
```

This means that the result you got differed from the expected results by a constant and such cases are considered correct in terms of indefinite integration.

It looks like you already learned about autoexpansion (thus the use of `factor` to keep the 2 from distributing). What you may not realize, however, is that once you pass an expression to a routine it is not required to keep your expression in factored form. It looks like you were expecting that the `x - 1` would be treated like `x`. We can simulate that as

```
>>> integrate(-x)+integrate(2*y).subs(y,x-1)
-x**2/2 + (x - 1)**2
```

Using `y` to represent `x - 1` is ok in this case since the results only differ by a constant:

```
>>> (integrate(x-1) - integrate(y).subs(y ,x-1)).is_constant()
True
```

It will not, however, be true for all functions of `x`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, doing this way I got the expected result!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you didn't pass any integration limits (from and to), so the only possible answer was the integrated formula.

If for example you want to integrate from 0 to inf, you need to pass this instead

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')

expr = - x + factor(2 * (x - 1))
int_1 = integrate(expr, (x,0, float('inf')))
print(int_1)
```

replace 0 and/or float('inf') by any numbers you want to evaluate.

Comment: OK. Just remember to check your assumptions that `as_y(expr)` is True where `as_y = lambda x: not x.has(y) and (integrate(x) - integrate(y).subs(y ,x)).is_constant()`